# How does CLR do on invoked by method in C#, VB.Net,

Tags: .net, clr

I don't know how to explain my question, please accept it in example form:

I wrote a library in C# language which has a method as below:

```
public object GetValueAt(int idx) {
    return arr[idx];
}
```

Then I use it in VB.Net, ofcourse there's a diffirent in index based between C# and VB.Net. So  if I call that method with `idx = 6`, how does CLR know object which I try to access (it having `idx = 5` on C#)?

That's just my example, and what about existed library in .Net?

Comment: Index 0 in C# == Index 0 in VB.Net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call that method from VB with `idx = 6` it will return `arr[6]` treating `arr` as 0-based (i.e. the seventh element), because the code is written in C#. No automatic rebasing is applied, because you're just calling a method from VB.

I *thought* the VB compiler automatically adjusts array indexes when the array indexing expression *itself* is in VB, but that's not the case here - it's just a method call. **EDIT**: It looks like that doesn't happen anyway, at least not always. The compiler makes allowances when *creating* arrays, but not indexing into them, apparently...

EDIT: That chimes in with the MSDN ["Arrays In Visual Basic"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx) page which shows an example and explains:

> The array students in the preceding example contains 7 elements. The indexes of the elements range from 0 through 6.

And from [this blog post](http://kcwebprogrammers.blogspot.com/2011/01/vb-arrays-vs-c-arrays-in-aspnet.html):

> As many long-time web developers may know, Visual Basic and VB Script used to have 1-based arrays for many years while just about every other language I used -- C, C++, JScript, JavaScript -- had 0-based arrays.  I didn't particularly have any strong preference for one over the other, but it was tricky to adjust your mind when switching from one to the other.
>
> Then when .Net was released, Visual Basic changed to using 0-based arrays.

Answer (score 6):

The only difference I'm aware of where you may believe there's an indexing difference between C# and VB.Net is when *declaring* an array.

In VB.Net, you declare the **upper bound** of the array:

```
Dim x(10) as Int32
```

declares an array with 11 elements, starting at 0, ending at 10. In C#, you declare the **length** of the array:

```
Int32 []x = new Int32[10];
```

declares an array with 10 elements, starting at 0, ending at 9.

Indexed *access* with identical index values works the same in both languages.

Comment: +1 Damien, spot on. This is a real VB idiosyncrasy. The 10 is the *upper bound*, not the size.